# Pass object by reference to a different object

Tags: c++, reference, mfc, pass-by-reference

I am building an MFC application where buttons located in a tab - and thus in a separate class - must access functions in certain objects to control motors and I/O.

There is one controller class in which all other objects are created. The controller object is created in the main MFC code. All functions can thus be called via the controller by using `controller.object.function`.

The buttons mentioned before are located in a different class and cannot access these functions by default so I need to give them access. I have written this test project and would like to get feedback on the way that I pass the object by reference.

Is this considered the correct way to pass an object by reference?

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA;
class ClassB;


class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB();
    void addOne();
    int b;
};

ClassB::ClassB() :
    b(0) {
}

void ClassB::addOne() {
    b = b + 1;
}


class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA(ClassB & B_ref);
    void addOneToB(); 
private:
    ClassB & B;
};

ClassA::ClassA(ClassB & B_ref) :
    B(B_ref) {
}

void ClassA::addOneToB() {
    B.addOne();
}


int main() {
    ClassB B;
    B.addOne();
    std::cout << B.b << "\n";

    ClassA A(B);
    A.addOneToB();
    std::cout << B.b << "\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Do note that since you have a reference members `A` is no longer copyable or movable.

Comment: @NathanOliver `A` is still copyable, it's not assignable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oops.  Forgot the assignable part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is fine, except that a class with a reference member is not movable and not assignable.

```
int main() {
    ClassB foo;
    ClassB bar;

    ClassA foo_wrapper(foo);
    ClassA bar_wrapper(bar);

    // Can't assign, won't compile!
    foo_wrapper = bar_wrapper;

    system("pause");
}
```

If your design would benefit from `ClassA` being movable or assignable, you use `ClassB * B;` instead.

```
class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA(ClassB & B_ref);
    void addOneToB();

private:
    ClassB * B;
};

ClassA::ClassA(ClassB & B_ref) :
    B(&B_ref) {
}

void ClassA::addOneToB() {
    B->addOne();
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I am not sure what the consequence would be if ClassA is not movable. ClassA in this case would simply be used for a tab in the GUI that holds buttons/fields and calls functions.